# Do enemies/monsters get gray dice?

Tags: monsters, victoriana

In Heresy-Engine based games (Airship Pirates, Victoriana 2E), do monsters have gray dice?

For example, if the Bestiary lists dogs as 4HD, do they get 4 ordinary health dice plus the 4 gray ones, resulting in (4+4)×2=16 pips, or do do they drop dead as soon as the original 4×2=8 pips are depleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**

I finally found an example in the first official Airship Pirates module "Ruined Empires". The monster stats on pages 21 and 22 have gray dice for the GM to tick.